# Route requests to index.html SPA - Angular2/AngularJS application in IBM websphere

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webserver, websphere

I am creating an angularjs application using angular ui router with Java backend rest api that runs in Websphere app server. AngularJS application is in a subfolder that is not read protected (browse directories is switched off).

When I use the application normally it works fine. But if I refresh the angularjs page with any other sub-route other than the main sub-route it says Cannot GET /xsubroute?xapp=xmyquerytoken.

Read in the docs that I have to redirect requests to index.html. How do I reconfigure my web.xml to redirect all requests for the angularjs app to get redirected to index.html.